# how to pass checkbox values into .load page using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a form with some checkboxes on which I want to post into a page (data.php) , but I want to load the page inside my page using the .load function with jquery so that I can check a checkbox and then update my query without the page have to reload. Can anyone help with the jquery code as i'm new with jquery and can't work out the code I need. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:

I have the following jquery which works, but I have 2 problems first one is the page im loading data.php has a pagination and when the links are clicked it returns no results because the page is reloading and returning to the default also I have 2 groups checkboxes each with a submit button both with the same id name ect and the top button submits the form loads the data in the page but for some reason the bottom submit button loads the actual data.php page and I don't understand why. If anyone can help or point in the right direction I would be very greatful. Thanks

here is my java script

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#submit").click(function() {   
   var action = $("#criteria").attr('action');
   var form_data = $('#criteria').serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend:function(){
  $('#loader').html('<center><img src="/images/loading-big.gif" alt="Loading..." align="absmiddle"/> loading...</center>').fadeIn('fast');;
          },
   success: function(data){
        $('#exercise_list').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        $("#loader").fadeOut('slow');
        }

    });     
    return false;
}); 
 return false;
});

 </script>
```

Comment: Can you show what code you have tried so that we can help? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bespoke service where you tell the community what you want and we develop code for you. Demonstrate that you have at least made an effort by showing the code you've written so far and we'll help you sort out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This works. When you know better about JQuery you see you can find some other ways

```
<div id="target" style="height:100px; width:100px; overflow: hidden"></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        if($(this)[0].checked) {
            if($(this).attr("id") === "chk1") {
                $("#target").load("http://www.google.fr"); 
            } else {
                $("#target").load("www.google.en"); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

you can use :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
```

click method is a shortcut for this

Comment: thanks for the code @mlwacosmos but it doesn't seem to work for me, I have updated my code above with what I have and the problems I have. Thanks

Comment: Note : the http and the other url are fake of course... you have to load something from your application

Comment: hi @mlwacosmos , is there a jquery code that will make the pagination links in the loaded page open without refreshing the page. maybe something that would make the #pagination a load inside the update div that data.php is loaded inside.